# Xamarin forms listview error

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have this page where I display some items using ListView.
The problem is when I go to this page it gives me an error `An unhandled exception occured` that I can't identify what its cause. How can identify the error or how can I fix this.

I'm still not that good so much in programming and trying to learn xamarin.

Class:

```
namespace MyMenu.Model
{
public class Sandwich
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImgSource { get; set; }

}
public class SandwichData
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Sandwich> SandwichList = new ObservableCollection<Sandwich>
        {
            new Sandwich {ID=1,Name="Bagel toast",Price=120.00m, ImgSource="test" },
            new Sandwich {ID=2,Name="Baked bean",Price=85.00m, ImgSource="test"},
            new Sandwich {ID=3,Name="Barros Jarpa", Price=85.00m, ImgSource="test"},
            new Sandwich {ID=4, Name="Chow mein", Price=95.00m, ImgSource="test"}
        };
}
}
```

xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyMenu.SandwichList"
         Padding="0,20,0,0"
         Title="Sandwiches">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

cs:

```
namespace MyMenu
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SandwichList : ContentPage
{
    public SandwichList ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        listView.ItemsSource = SandwichData.SandwichList;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `How can identify the error` Keep cutting bits of XAML and code out until it works. When it works, the last thing you removed was likely the problem. [mcve]

Comment: Try removing the static from the `SandwichList` and set the `ItemSource` like this `listView.ItemsSource = new SandwichData().SandwichList;`

Comment: Do you initialize `SandwitchList` anywhere? Cause looks like you assign an uninitialized List

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I tried it and it gives same result

Comment: @StamatisStiliats nope.

Comment: Put a try catch block around listview.itemsource, and check what the error is

Comment: In addition to the try catch block, set a breakpoint on the listView.ItemsSource line. Then you'll be able to see if Sandwich list is set to anything.

Comment: @Saruman is correct, put in the try catch. Use catch(Exception ex){  }.  In debugging, you can put the mouse cursor over ex and see what the exception is.